# Changing background image depending on variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am really unfamiliar with the javascript and I have this little task to handle. The main idea of this task to read input from Flask and depending on that input change the numbers on the website and background. The numbers and values change without a problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to change the background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>

  .bggif1 {
background-image: url(Alert.gif);
}

.bggif2 {
background-image: url(Driving.gif);
}

.bggif3 {
background-image: url(Pulling.gif);
}

<table>

<thead><tr><th>Current action</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>{{ vaction }}</td></tr></tbody>

</table>

<script>
if vaction === "Driving"
   bggif2
if vaction === "Sounding The Alarm"
   bggif1
if vaction === "Pulling"
   bggif3
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is an example code, I don't need finished code I would just appreciate any tips or advice because I am stuck on the background changing according to the `{{ vaction }}` variable.

Python part of the code :

```
print('Are the eyes Open or Closed?: ')
estate1 = input()
print('Does the Driver look to the Front or to the Side?(Front or Side): ')
hstate1 = input()
print('Is The body facing Front or to the Side? (Front or Side): ')
bstate1 = input()
print('Is the car functioning properly? (Working or NotWorking): ')
vstate1 = input()
vaction1 = 'Driving'

# Outcomes of the answers
if estate1 == 'Closed':
    elevel1 = 2
else:
    elevel1 = 1

if hstate1 == 'Side':
    hlevel1 = 2
else:
    hlevel1 = 1

if bstate1 == 'Side':
    blevel1 = 2
else:
    blevel1 = 1

if vstate1 == 'NotWorking':
    vlevel1 = 2
else:
    vlevel1 = 1


# Vehicle actions according to the answers
if elevel1 == 2 or hlevel1 == 2 or blevel1 == 2:
    vaction1 = 'Sounding The Alarm'
if elevel1 == 1 and hlevel1 == 1 and blevel1 == 1 and vlevel1 == 1:
    vaction1 = 'Driving'
if vlevel1 == 2:
    vaction1 = 'Pulling over'


# Inputs are being over writen as the website page variables
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("Index.html", estate=estate1, hstate=hstate1, 
bstate=bstate1, vstate=vstate1, vaction=vaction1, elevel=elevel1, 
          hlevel=hlevel1, blevel=blevel1, vlevel=vlevel1)
```

Comment: What is this templating? `<td>{{ vaction }}</td>`

Comment: I think it's Jinja Syntax, he said he's using Flask so that should be Jinja

Comment: I uploaded the python part

Comment: Did you actually try my solution? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the vaction value from the server (Flask server), and you are using Jinja templates, so you need to change your script to be

```
var vaction = "{{vaction}}";
  if(vaction === "Driving")
    // do something
  else if(vaction === "Sounding The Alarm")
    //do something
  else if(vaction === "Pulling")
    // do something
```

instead of

```
if vaction === "Driving"
   bggif2
if vaction === "Sounding The Alarm"
   bggif1
if vaction === "Pulling"
   bggif3
```

and vaction isn't even defined, you need to use {{}} for template variable

Comment: That's up to him I just showed him how to do that, he want to do it that way, he doesn't need flexibility maybe, he could do requests with AJAX to get the value with flexibility...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const bg = {
  "Driving": "bggif2",
  "Sounding The Alarm": "bggif1",
  "Pulling": "bggif3"
}

const vaction = "Sounding The Alarm"; // "{{vaction}}"

document.querySelector("body").classList.add(bg[vaction]);
```

```css
.bggif1 {
  background-image: url(http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Alert-Download-PNG.png);
}

.bggif2 {
  background-image: url(Driving.gif);
}

.bggif3 {
  background-image: url(Pulling.gif);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Current action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sounding The Alarm</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

A function like this will change the background of an element with id = bggif

```
    const changeImage = () => {
        if (vaction === "Driving") {
            document.querySelector("#bggif").style.backgroundImage = "url('Driving.gif')"
        } else if (vaction === "Sounding The Alarm") {
        document.querySelector("#bggif").style.backgroundImage = "url('Alert.gif')"
        } else {
        document.querySelector("#bggif").style.backgroundImage = "url('Pulling.gif')"
        }
    }
```